# Safety Backup Light

Tags: led

A set of lights is controlled by a 15 minute timer.   Although most of the time 
customers finish storing / retrieving their items in under 15 minutes, some may exceed the 15 minute timer limit and need to reset another 15 minutes.  At best, this is irritating: usually I can use my cellphone to illuminate my way back to the switch.

If an circuit design (preferably an existing device):

1. could provide LED light for one minute
2. charged in 2 minutes from a 120V source &
3. discharged its current through the LED immediately after AC power is removed

The goal is to provide ~1 minute of LED illumination to get back to the 15 minute switch.  Is there such a design (or even a device) out there?

Comment: Honestly I just leave a small LED burning 24x7, directly over the thrones.  It's enough they can see by, but not up to official lighting stndard.   It's just not worth the additional complication to try to have some sort of active solution for "I'm in the toilet stall and the sensor can't see me".

Comment: Have you seen https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260142/need-single-shot-1-minute-delay-off-led-circuit? Basically an LED on a fat capacitor?

Comment: @Harper - I second this -- a 2W LED running 24/7 would cost a couple of dollars a year to run. No need to overcomplicate things to create  a backup LED that runs an extra minute when it costs so little to have the backup LED run all the time.

Comment: How about having a locator LED at the timer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a timed light use a light with an occupancy sensor.
[Here is an example I found by searching for 'occupancy sensor switch'](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-2-Amp-Single-Pole-Occupancy-Sensing-Switch-White-MS-OPS2H-WH/203202128) . These work of a motion sensor and turn the circuit on whenever there is something moving. It will turn the circuit off after some period of time where no motion is detected.

This is a better solution because it is only on when needed and does not require any backup system.